# Emulator - Loading App

Tags: android, emulation

I'm still learning how to use the dev tools.  Using MotoDev which is Eclipse, I wrote a basic "hello world" app.  When I run the program, the emulator starts up.  It took a few restarts of the emulator and Eclipse until my Hello World icon appear in the emulator.  I noticed at one point that a status message said it was sending over the .apl file, which is when my app finally appeared in the emulator.  I made changes to my code (Hello to Goodbye) and now..I can't figure out how to "send" to changed app to the emulator.  The original app is not being replaced with the changes. What do I need to be doing to reload the changed application on to the Android emulator?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I havn't used MotoDev but I assume its pretty similar to the Google Dev plugin. In Eclipse go to:

Window > Android SDK and AVD manager

Under "Virtual Devices" select the AVD you have created and hit start.

Next go to Run > Run

When asked "Select a way to run ###" select Android Application

If you check your console you should get a message indicating the app is being installed, give it 30 seconds max and your app should be installed.